# Child Window Template SilverLight 3

Tags: silverlight-3.0

How to change the GUI of the child window in silverlight , how to apply template or style any good example reference will help.
thanks in advance

For addition information:
I would like to change the title bar shape, the close button shape and the body area shape as well, you can say I want to change the View of the childWidow control.

Comment: It would help if you provided some idea in what way you want to change Child window?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the template as outputted from Blend.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ChildWindowControlTemplate1" TargetType="controls:ChildWindow">
    <Grid x:Name="Root">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="#02FFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz2">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz1">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.95" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="X"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.85" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="X"/>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz2">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz1">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="X"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Path x:Name="X_Fuzz2" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" Fill="#14C51900" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#14C51900" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9">
                                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1.3" ScaleX="1.3"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                                </Path>
                                <Path x:Name="X_Fuzz1" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" Fill="#1EC51900" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#1EC51900" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9">
                                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1.1" ScaleX="1.1"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                                </Path>
                                <Path x:Name="X_Fuzz0" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" Fill="#FFC51900" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FFC51900" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9"/>
                                <Path x:Name="X" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="0.7" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9">
                                    <Path.Stroke>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF313131" Offset="1"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF8E9092" Offset="0"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Path.Stroke>
                                </Path>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Overlay">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="1"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0,0.5,1" KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="1.05"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.55" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="1"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0,0.5,1" KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="1.05"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.55" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Overlay">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1.05"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1.05"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid x:Name="Overlay" Background="{TemplateBinding OverlayBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Opacity="{TemplateBinding OverlayOpacity}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Border BorderBrush="#14000000" BorderThickness="1" Background="#14000000" CornerRadius="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="#0F000000" BorderThickness="1" Background="#0F000000" CornerRadius="2.25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="#0C000000" BorderThickness="1" Background="#0C000000" CornerRadius="2.5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="#0A000000" BorderThickness="1" Background="#0A000000" CornerRadius="2.75" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#FFFFFFFF" CornerRadius="2">
                <Border CornerRadius="1.5" Margin="1">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E8EB" Offset="1"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFF6F8F9" Offset="0"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Width="Auto" Background="{StaticResource LightBackground}">
                            <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" Margin="6,0,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" Foreground="White"/>
                                <Button x:Name="CloseButton1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="14" IsTabStop="False" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Foreground="White"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

HTH, Stimul8d